# Can't suspend to ram since linux 3.8 kernel - 16.04LTS

Tags: 16.04, kernel, 20.04, suspend, motherboard

With ASRock N68C-S UCC motherboard, suspend always works until ubuntu 12.04 include.
But not since 3.11 kernel (even with 12.04).
Also, suspend don't work with 14.04 and 16.04.
I would like to make it work with 16.04.
Any advice welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: check https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302

Comment: Thanks. I'll make many tests and then report to launchpad if not fixed.

Comment: @Rmano: no solution for my case, I'll open new bug.

Comment: reported here:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1606178

Comment: Precedent report aborted. Workaround using `$ sudo acpitool -W 5; sudo acpitool -W 6`. The very first suspend after a boot can be long: about 5min (sometimes more) to wake up! Few times, it don't wake up. After the very first complete resume, the others works always quickly and perfectly. Better do the very first suspend at the login state.

Comment: Still exactly the same with ubuntu20.04 :/