# Can't suspend properly (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: suspend

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 for a few days (I used Windows before). However, as soon as my computer is suspended, it automatically turns on. I tried closing the lid and the screen was turn off (I opened the lid a little bit to check) but the computer was still running. I have looked through a lot of topics and none of them worked for me.

Comment: Same problem but with tower PC.
try this:https://askubuntu.com/questions/797390/cant-suspend-to-ram-since-linux-3-8-kernel-16-04lts

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049178/suspend-instantly-restarting-editing-acpi-wakeup-with-systemd-service